# Spring & JUnit 5 - How to clear database when @AfterAll must be static

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-test, junit5

@BeforeAll and @AfterAll have to be static. So I can't use JdbcTemplate. How should I empty the database?

I have now initialized the data in a method with @PostConstruct. But I couldn't find a working counterpart. I had thought about adding a counter to @AfterEach and deleting the database at the last execution. But this is not a very nice workaround.

Comment: AfterClass already required the annotated method to be static. So what's the difference? Besides, JUnit5 *allows* AfterAll methods not to be static: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-test-instance-lifecycle

Comment: Sorry my mistake! But thank you very much for the solution. If you had put it in an answer, I could mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@AfterClass` in JUnit 4 required the annotated method to be `static`. So there's no difference: if you could use `@AfterClass` in JUnit 4, you can still use `@AfterAll` in JUnit Jupiter.

The difference, however, is that JUnit Jupiter *allows* `@AfterAll`-annotated methods *not* to be static. See [the documentation](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-test-instance-lifecycle) for how to allow that.